# WPF TreeView DataBinding: data not shown, BindingExpression path error

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I'm working on a new functionality for Visual Studio Add-in. Initially the project's target framework was 3.5. But I was asked to add a Tool Window with quite complicated UI using WPF and switch to 4.0 framework (maybe this is important)
I'm trying to bind hierarchical data to the Tree View inside my Tool Window which is originally a WPF User Control.

But I see the following error:
"System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PoolList' property not found on 'object' ''OpjectPool' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PoolList; DataItem='OpjectPool' (Name=''); target element is 'TreeView' (Name='treeView1'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')"

This is a Class which represents data I need to bind to the tree view.

```
class CodeItem
{
public TextPoint StartPoint { get; set; }
public TextPoint EndPoint { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public vsCMElement Kind { get; set; }
public CodeElements ChildClasses { get; set; }
public ProjectItem ProjectItem { get; set; }
public List<CodeItem> CodeItems { get; set; }
public string Label { get; set; }

public CodeItem(CodeElement el)
{
    StartPoint = el.StartPoint;
    EndPoint = el.EndPoint;
    Name = el.Name;
    Kind = el.Kind;
    ChildClasses = el.Children;
    ProjectItem = el.ProjectItem;
    Label = Kind.ToString();

    CodeItems = new List<CodeItem>();
    if (ChildClasses.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (CodeElement elem in ChildClasses)
        {
            if (elem.Kind.ToString() == "vsCMElementClass")
            {
                CodeItems.Add(new CodeItem(elem));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my UserControl code:

```
public partial class OpjectPool : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<CodeItem> PoolList = new ObservableCollection<CodeItem>();

    public OpjectPool()
    {

        Project pr = ... // getting VS Project we want to work with;

        foreach (ProjectItem item in pr.ProjectItems.Item("Objects").ProjectItems)
        {
            if (item.FileCodeModel != null)
            {
                CodeItem rootPoolItem = new CodeItem(item.Name);

                foreach (CodeElement el in item.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)
                {
                    if (el.Kind.ToString() == "vsCMElementClass" || el.Kind.ToString() == "vsCMElementNamespace")
                    {
                        CodeItem ci = new CodeItem(el);

                        rootPoolItem.CodeItems.Add(ci);

                    }
                }

                PoolList.Add(rootPoolItem);
            }
        }

        InitializeComponent();

        this.treeView1.DataContext = this;
   }
}
```

And Here is a XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="******.OpjectPool"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Height="Auto" Name="maingrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <TreeView Height="Auto" Name="treeView1" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding PoolList}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding CodeItems}" >
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Label}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
             </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Name="dataGrid1" Width="Auto" FrozenColumnCount="3" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="scrollViewer3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto" Name="dataGrid2" Width="Auto" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Name="gridSplitter1" ResizeDirection="Columns" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2" Name="gridSplitter2" ResizeDirection="Columns" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="2" />
</Grid>
```

PoolList is not null and contains a full hierarchical structure I need to bind.
Interesting that error message says about real and not null property of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error states:

BindingExpression path error: 'PoolList' **PROPERTY** not found on 'object' ''OpjectPool' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PoolList;

`PoolList` is not a property.

Comment: You are right Rafal, Since I'm a new in C# and used Jave before I just didn't realize this simple thing, after checking C# reference I defined PoolList as public static ObservableCollection<CodeItem> PoolList { get; set; } and it works, thank you